# Delete object inside a function: ugly, error-prone, inefficient, and usually not exception-safe

Tags: c++, memory, virtual-destructor

According to the following article: [Why isn’t the destructor called at the end of scope?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt)

Code that creates an object using new and then deletes it at the end of the same scope is ugly, error-prone, inefficient, and usually not exception-safe. For example:

```
 void very_bad_func()    // ugly, error-prone, and inefficient
    {
        X* p = new X;
        // use p
        delete p;  // not exception-safe
    }
```

---

## My Code which I hope is not ugly:

I am creating an object of type `TiXmlDocument`and the delete it by the end of the function.

```
void DataLoader::readXmlFile(const string & file)
{
    TiXmlDocument *doc = new TiXmlDocument(file.c_str());
    bool loadOkay = doc->LoadFile();
    TiXmlHandle hdl(doc);

    //work is done in here
    if(loadOkay)
    {
        TiXmlElement * pRoot = hdl.FirstChildElement().Element();//.FirstChildElement().Element();
        parseFile(pRoot);
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"Error: "<< doc->ErrorDesc()<<endl;
    }
    //deallocate doc
    delete doc;
}
```

---

## Question(s):

- Should I use `DataLoader::~DataLoader() {}` destructor in order to insure that the object is deleted after I leave the scope of the function? without the need of explicitly deleting it `delete doc`.

---

As suggested I did the following:

```
TiXmlDocument doc(xmlFile.c_str());
bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();
TiXmlHandle hdl(&doc);
```

I am starting to think that using dynamic memory just like java and c# is not a good practice (**should be used in a responsible way**) in c++. If there is no real cause to use it then don't. If not handled correctly it will cause a memory leak which is hard to trace.

---

Comment: Do you mean something like [smart pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx)? `std::unique_ptr<iXmlDocument> doc(new TiXmlDocument(file.c_str()));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either create your object without new:

```
void func()
{
    X p;
    // use p
}
```

Or if you must use new (for example, it's a big object) then use a smart pointer:

```
void func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<X> p(new X);
    // use p
}
```

Problem solved!

Comment: What I did is the following please check question

Comment: @HaniGoc: Don't be a help vampire. One question at a time.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry my mistake. I'll remove the last part.

Comment: @Neil Kirk i think it's suit me well. It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's still ugly (in my view), and certainly error-prone, inefficient, and not exception-safe. If an exception is thrown during this function, the `delete` won't happen, and you'll leak memory.

In this case, there's no need for `new` at all; use an automatic variable, which will be destroyed automatically when the function exits, whether by reaching the end, returning, or throwing.

```
TiXmlDocument doc(file.c_str());
```

If you did need dynamic allocation for some reason, then use a smart pointer or other [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511) type to get the same automatic behaviour:

```
auto doc = std::make_unique<TiXmlDocument>(file.c_str());            // C++14 or later
std::unique_ptr<TiXmlDocument> doc(new TiXmlDocument(file.c_str())); // C++11
```

To answer the last question: use the destructor to deallocate resources managed by the class instance, not transient resources used within a function call. Again, you should usually use RAII types as member variables to manage these resources automatically, so that you don't need to write a destructor yourself.

Comment: @HaniGoc: Yes, if you still want to use `new` rather than an automatic variable for some reason, that looks right, assuming `TiXmlHandle` doesn't do something silly like delete the pointer that it's given.

Comment: I don't know what `TiXmlHandle`will do that's the problem. So I think it's better as you said to use smart pointers right?

Comment: @HaniGoc: If you don't know whether `TiXmlHandle` might try to delete it, then there's nothing you can safely do. You'll need to find out why it takes a pointer, and whether or not it expects to take ownership. If it does expect to delete it, then you'll need `new` with no `delete` (and no smart pointer). If it doesn't, then there's no good reason to use `new` at all - make it a local variable.

Comment: @HaniGoc If you don't know what a function will do with a pointer you pass it, then you shouldn't call the function..